# C: Why static variables can't be linked externally like globals

Tags: c

Firmware and compiler point of view, Why static variables can't be linked externally like globals.

Comment: Globals are static in a sense they are allocated once and live for the whole time the program is executing. the `static` qualifier on a global is explicitly setting it to internal linkage. It is like asking why locked doors can't be opened.

Comment: `static` applied to a variable makes it local to a file. Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856599/when-to-use-static-keyword-before-global-variables

Answer (score 2):

The `static` keyword serves double duty here.  It specifies that the *object* has static storage duration - that is, storage for the object is allocated when the program starts and released when the program exits.

It also specifies that the *identifier* for that object has *internal linkage*.  IOW, the identifier is not exported to the linker (it is effectively "private" to that translation unit).

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**
> 1     An identifier declared in different scopes or in the same scope more than once can be
> made to refer to the same object or function by a process called *linkage*.
> <sup>29)</sup> There are
> three kinds of linkage: external, internal, and none.
> 2     In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an entire program, each
> declaration of a particular identifier with *external linkage* denotes the same object or
> function. Within one translation unit, each declaration of an identifier with *internal
> linkage* denotes the same object or function. Each declaration of an identifier with *no
> linkage* denotes a unique entity.
> 3     If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage class
> specifier **`static`**, the identifier has internal linkage.<sup>30)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>29) There is no linkage between different identifiers.
>
> 30) A function declaration can contain the storage-class specifier **`static`** only if it is at file scope; see
> 6.7.1.</sup>

If you want an object to have static storage duration, but also have its identifier visible to other translation units, then you must declare it at file scope *without* the static keyword:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i_am_static_and_visible;
static int i_am_static_but_not_visible;

void foo( void )
{
  static int i_am_static_but_not_visible_either;
  ...
}
```